# Karma doesn't load node_module/*/package.json to PhantomJS (404 Error)

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm using Karma 0.13.22
 Node v6.7.0
 npm 3.10.3 
 and PhantomJS 2.1.1

Using the angular 2 seed as a basis and when I run npm test I receive the following error:

```
25 10 2016 20:08:29.857:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 3G6Eu905pwciAA 3BAAAA with id 70262326
25 10 2016 20:08:30.128:WARN [web-server]:404: /node_modules/@angular/core/package.json
25 10 2016 20:08:30.131:WARN [web-server]: 404: /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/pack age.json
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/package.json
Error loading http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/package.json'
```

I've tried including all json files in a pattern in my karma.conf.js, didn't work. 
 I have the correct baseURL and basePath as far as I can tell.

Any idea where I might look to resolve this issue?

Update: If I use baseURL: '/base/'

I get error:

```
26 10 2016 08:33:13.764:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/ng2-translate.js
26 10 2016 08:33:13.809:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/lodash.js
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not    Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/ng2-translate.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/ng2-translate.js as "ng2-translate" from http://localhost:9876/base/dist/dev/app/app.component.js'
```

I tried to resolve this by adding

```
{ pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
{ pattern: 'node_modules/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
'node_modules/ng2-translate.js'
```

to my karma.conf.js, but that did nothing to resolve the issue

Comment: You might need to use a karma proxy; the karma files are served from `/base/`, if I remember correctly. Including your `karma.conf.js` would be helpful.

Comment: When I use /base/ I get an error saying it can't find /node_modules/ng2-translate.js . I'll see if I can add that to my karma.conf.js